# Can a page in the web forces an android application to open it in a browser?

Tags: android, web, browser

I have control over the webpage but not over the aplication.

The thing is that my site works in google chrome/firefox of the android, but not in the webview of the app.

Can I change the header or something like that to force the android application to open it in a real browser instead of inside the application??

Comment: nope ..a web page can not force itself to open in a particular browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
  webview_chart.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webview_chart.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview_chart.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    webview_chart.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            progress_bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {
            progress_bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    });
    webview_chart.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cm) {
            Log.d(TAG, cm.message() + " -- From line "
                    + cm.lineNumber() + " of "
                    + cm.sourceId() + "  " + cm.toString());
            return true;
        }
    });
 webview_chart.loadUrl("http://demo.com");
```

//  check the logs by using this .
// this is gonna work because usually webpages need javascript enabled

Comment: But this code I should insert in the Android application right? I am searching for a solution in the webpage.

Comment: well then try to stop using javascript and and session storage becuase you need to declare that while using webviews